# Querying _PARTITIONTIME only yields a date

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I attempted to query _PARTITIONTIME in my ingestion time partitioned table. Upon doing so, I realized that each row produced an identical incorrect timestamp: 2019-02-25 00:00:00 UTC. I attempted to extract specific 'parts' of _PARTITIONTIME, but all of them excluding the date yielded 0.

Although data is streamed into the table, it is actually inserted in batches every 10 minutes or so(as far as I understand). As a followup question, when is _PARTITIONTIME calculated? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149447/bigquery-streaming-and-partitions-when-is-partitiontime-really-evaluated), but I only understood the flow, not when it's actually calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_PARTITIONTIME` is more like a `_PARTITIONDATE` - you shouldn't expect it to contain the exact time when the record was streamed, but the date that partition belongs to.

> Ingestion-time partitioned tables include a pseudo column named _PARTITIONTIME that contains a date-based timestamp for data that is loaded into the table. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: Hmm. So to clarify, there's no way to increase accuracy beyond date? I was hoping to use it to calculate how long it takes data to travel through my pipeline and land into BQ. My plan was to manually publish a sample message, then find it in BQ,  and get its ingestion time.

Comment: I have a timestamp column. In fact, I normally partition over it. That being said, how could that timestamp give me BQ insertion time?

Comment: I would give that responsibility to whichever function is actually inserting the data into BQ.

Comment: My parser inserts data into BQ. I can put it there, but then my calculations wouldn't account for the time it takes for data to get from the parser to actual insertion. That being said, that's better than nothing and should be close.

Answer (score 0):

As of [September 21, 2020](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#September_21_2020), the hourly time partitioning feature is GA. For tables partitioned by hour, BQ insertion writes to the partition hour 00 by default, unless the partition to write to is explicitly specified at insertion/ingestion time. The partition can be specified using `$YYYYMMDDHH` or along the lines of the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO
  project_id.dataset.mytable (
    _PARTITIONTIME,
    field1,
    field2)
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP "2008-12-25 15:30:00+00", HOUR, "UTC"),
  1,
  "one"
```